# How to add Custom Libraries to Default Solution Template?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2008

How to add my own libraries to project template in visual studio 
For shared.dll like System.data
I don't want to add shared.dll again n again for new Project.
Kindly Suggest Some Solution

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, create a `C# Project Template`:

```
File->New Project->Visual C#->C# Project Template
```

Then open `ProjectTemplate.csproj` file in the editor and add your references there:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\MyLibrary\shred.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Don't forget to replace the properties of the `Reference` tag with that of your library.
After building your project, copy the output zip file into the Visual Studio project templates folder:

```
My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#
```

Comment: Hi this is great but when i use this intellisence  in not working.

Comment: @Abhi_Dev: Where? Do you mean after creating a new C# project form your template project, the intellisence is not working is your project's .cs files? I tested this and found no problems. Are you sure about that?

Comment: yes but i don't know why ,can't figure out  where is the problem.

Comment: @Abhi_Dev: Can you send me the template you have created?

Answer (score 0):

The easier option is to use `Export Template` option in the file menu.

Create a project in Visual Studio and perform your necessary changes to the project (adding references, etc).
Then from the `File` menu, select `Export Template...`.

Also there is a Visual Studio Extension called  [Export Template Wizard](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24). Installing this extension will add anther menu item above the `Export Template...` option: `Export Template as VSIX`.
Difference between these two are that the VSIX one gives you an installable Visual Studio Extension that can be easily installed on any computer.